# Problems transferring photos from Lumix camera to computer

Tags: photos

I have a Lumix DMC-ZX3 camera and have always been able to transfer photos from the camera onto my computer.  However, the last time I tried to do so I got two DCIM files (PANA 100 and PANA 101) - usually I only get PANA 100.  I can transfer photos from the PANA 100 file but not from the PANA 101 file.  Can anyone explain why I have two files and why I cant transfer photos from the second file?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal operation for many/most digital cameras.  It just means that you've taken more than 10,000 photos on your camera.

The first image you take is generally stored to /DCIM/PANA100/IMG_0000.JPG, the second to /DCIM/PANA100/IMG_0001.JPG, and so on.  The 10,000th image is stored as /DCIM/PANA100/IMG_9999.JPG... so where does it store the 10,000st image?  It can't re-use /DCIM/PANA100/IMG_0000.JPG, because you may still have that image (either on the camera, or on your PC where you'd get the two images confused after moving them).

So... it creates a new directory, and stores your image as:  /DCIM/PANA101/IMG_0000.JPG

Every 10,000 images, it will create a new directory.

I'm not sure what happens after 9,000,000 images, when it's used /DCIM/PANA999/IMG_9999.JPG, and is ready to create a new file...

I have no idea why you "can't transfer photos from the second file"--please show us your error message so we can help with that.